# Overriding themeroller style for links

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, css-selectors, anchor

I'm attempting to override themeroller's theme for a specific link.

The code for all links is:

```
.ui-body-c .ui-link:link {
    color:      #000000      /*{c-body-link-color}*/;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.ui-body-c .ui-link:visited {
    color:      #000000      /*{c-body-link-visited}*/;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.ui-body-c .ui-link:active {
    color:      #000000      /*{c-body-link-active}*/;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.ui-body-c .ui-link:hover {
    color:      #00b2ef !important     /*{c-body-link-hover}*/;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

I've created a new link and would like to have it's :link color be different than the other links.  I added the class .newlink which is:

```
.newlink:link{
    color: #00b2ef
}
```

No matter where I place this class, or if I add selectors (either the other 2 classes that are above along with the .newlink selector or a unique id for this link) the link still inherits the themeroller style.  When I view the inherited style using firebug, any styles I add are always crossed out.  I thought adding the extra class to the selector (.ui-body-c .ui-link .newlink:link{...}) would increase this rules weight for the link, but that doesn't work.  I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks, everyone!

Comment: You're missing a semicolon `;` after your hex color code.

Comment: Make sure you are ending your statements correctly... `color: #000000` should be `color: #000000;`

Comment: The semicolon is hidden behind the comment

Comment: Not for `.newlink:link`

Comment: Please use `!important` as a last resort and not in every CSS class. There should be no reason to use it and it can get tricky to debug.

Comment: Themeroller added the !important statement, I believe.  I will remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path about increasing the weight you just need to remove the space in between .ui-body-c .ui-link.newlink:link{...} to say the ui-link that has the newlink class...

It has to be added below to override the above code. (ui-link)

```
.ui-body-c .ui-link.newlink:link {
    color:      #000000      /*{c-body-link-color}*/;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

unless you plan on removing the ui-link class... then you need to rewrite the css...
maybe something like this:

```
.ui-body-c a.newlink:link {
    color:      #000000      /*{c-body-link-color}*/;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.ui-body-c a.newlink:visited {
    color:      #000000      /*{c-body-link-visited}*/;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.ui-body-c a.newlink:active {
    color:      #000000      /*{c-body-link-active}*/;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.ui-body-c a.newlink:hover {
    color:      #00b2ef !important;     /*{c-body-link-hover}*/
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Comment: Removing the space between .ui-link and .newlink has pretty much worked. It's working in IE, but for some reason Firefox is still displaying the color for that specific link as black rather than the blue.  However, firebug shows that it inherited the right color, and black is crossed out...

Comment: Try to add the `.ui-body-c a.ui-link.newlink:link` in the css like the example above

Comment: Still appears black in Firefox.  Works in Chrome and IE.  I know that the color isn't the issue as it's the hover color for the regular links.  It's also strange that the color declaration for .ui-body-c .ui-link:link is crossed out in firebug, yet it still appears black.

Comment: Do you have the link to the page where this problem is persisting. In a situation like this you could always use !important as a last resort. In this context it may be acceptable because you override.

Comment: This ended up working.  Not sure why it wasn't prior to that, but I tried it again the next day and worked in all browsers.  Thanks!